# Tango With Django - How Bootstrap changes the syntax

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working through Tango with Django -> http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/bootstrap.html#the-login-page

and in the tutorial, there is a mention of:

> Besided adding in a link to the bootstrap signin.css, and a series of
>   changes to the classes associated with elements, we have removed the
>   code that automatically generates the login form, i.e. form.as_p.
>   Instead, we took the elements, and importantly the id of the elements
>   generated and associated them with the elements in this bootstrapped
>   form.

And I see that the form.as_p is removed, but I'm failing to see how bootstrap 'knows' to associate all the form requirements, can anyone explain how this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't know anything.

If you use `{{ form.as_p }}` in your templates to render your forms, Django will automatically give the following output:

```
<p><input type="text" id="id_username" name="username"></p>
<p><input type="password" id="id_password" name="password"></p>
```

So, In that tutorial, instead of using `{{ form.as_p }}`, they are **manually** writing the HTML code required for `input` fields. There is no difference as long as the `name` of each `input` field is correct.

Comment: Ahh I see - I didn't quite get what {{ form.as_p }} would output, but this makes sense now. And so would the django-bootstrap-toolkit then remove that manual effort and revert to a {{ form.as_p }} type of link?

Comment: @ploo I've never actually used django-bootstrap-toolkit but after taking a quick look at their docs, you've to use `{{ form|as_bootstrap }}` instead of `{{ form.as_p }}`. This would, of course, save you the hassle of doing anything manually.